# Isolating orders when performing regular asymptotic expansions

Tags: differential-equations

I tried to perform a regular asymptotic expansion on the

```
pde = D[p[x, t], t, t] (1 + eps Ca + eps Cd Sign[D[p[x, t], t]]) + D[p[x, t], x, x]
```

Substituting the asymptotic power series

```
pdeasym = pde /. p -> p0[x, t] + eps *p1[x, t] + eps^2* p2[x, t]
```

and isolating the leading order

```
orders = CoefficientList[pdeasym, eps];
pde0 = orders[[1]] == 0;
```

yields
    [image]

which does include eps orders.

I assume this occurs since the eps in within the derivatives, but I didn't find a way to fix this. How can I isolate only the order eps^0, eps^1 terms and so on?

Answer (score 3):

You can fix your problem as follows:

```
pdeasym =pde /. p -> Function[{x, t}, p0[x, t] + eps*p1[x, t] + eps^2*p2[x, t]]
```

Here the substitution rule also applies to the derivatives of p.

```
CoefficientList[pdeasym, eps]
```

Comment: It works. Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome.